# Tkinter Resize text to contents

Tags: python, tkinter

Is it possible to have a Tkinter text widget resize to fit its contents?

ie: if I put 1 line of text it will shrink, but if I put 5 lines it will grow

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The only way I can think of accomplishing this is to calculate the width and height every time the user enters text into the Text widget and then set the size of the widget to that. But the limitation here is that only mono-spaced fonts will work correctly, but here it is anyway:

```
import Tkinter

class TkExample(Tkinter.Frame):
   def __init__(self, parent):
      Tkinter.Frame.__init__(self, parent)
      self.init_ui()

   def init_ui(self):
      self.pack()
      text_box = Tkinter.Text(self)
      text_box.pack()
      text_box.bind("<Key>", self.update_size)

   def update_size(self, event):
      widget_width = 0
      widget_height = float(event.widget.index(Tkinter.END))
      for line in event.widget.get("1.0", Tkinter.END).split("\n"):
         if len(line) > widget_width:
            widget_width = len(line)+1
      event.widget.config(width=widget_width, height=widget_height)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = Tkinter.Tk()
    TkExample(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: yeah, that is what I figured.  Was hoping I missed some method somewhere.  Ah well, I'll live.

Comment: You can use `font_measure` to get the actual width of a line of text in a variable-width font. Also, this suffers from the fact that your binding fires before the text is inserted. You need to either bind on `<KeyRelease>` or fiddle with the bind tags so that your binding happens after the class bindings.

Comment: lines = event.widget.get("1.0", Tkinter.END).split("\n");
widget_height = max(imap(len, lines)+1

Comment: What about tabs? In my experience, those are as long as 8 other characters in the default mono font that `Tkinter.Text` is using for me (on OS X 10.10.)

Answer (score 6):

Found this thread at the top of a Google search and, therefore, maybe someone who needs this will find it.  Couldn't find the answer even after hours of searching.  So here's the HACK I came up with.

I wanted a popup window that form-fits itself correctly around any unknown, yet predetermined text in a Text widget, rather than user input.  Also, the Text widget needs to form-fit itself correctly around its text content.

A `tkinter.Label` works great, but it doesn't have `tkinter.Text.tag_configure`, and `tkinter.Text.tag_bind` which I needed to replace some HTML tags with tkinter's rich text tags.  `tkinter.Text` has rich text tags, but does not expand nicely, while `tkinter.Label` expands nicely but does not have rich text tags.  Moreover, I just hate scrollbars and word wrap, unless they're REALLY needed.  This does exactly what I wanted it to.  Although, this is just a very simple, working abstract for this forum.  Works with any font.  Only tested with Python 3.3 in Ubuntu 13.10 (Linux).

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import tkinter as tk

class MyFrame(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self)

        root = self.master
        root.title("My Window Title")

        # Pack Frame into root window and make it expand in "both" x and y
        self.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=10, pady=10)
        # Statistical weight of 1 = 100% for cell (0, 0) to expand 100%
        self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)

        # The string text
        text = """Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit, sed
diam nonummy nibh euismod tincidunt ut laoreet dolore magna
aliquam erat volutpat. Ut wisi enim ad minim veniam, quis
nostrud exerci tation ullamcorper suscipit lobortis nisl ut
aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis autem vel eum iriure
dolor in hendrerit in vulputate velit esse molestie consequat,
vel illum dolore eu feugiat nulla facilisis at vero eros et
accumsan et iusto odio dignissim qui blandit praesent luptatum
zzril delenit augue duis dolore te feugait nulla facilisi. Nam
liber tempor cum soluta nobis eleifend option congue nihil
imperdiet doming id quod mazim placerat facer possim assum.
Typi non habent claritatem insitam; est usus legentis in iis qui
facit eorum claritatem. Investigationes demonstraverunt lectores
legere me lius quod ii legunt saepius. Claritas est etiam
processus dynamicus, qui sequitur mutationem consuetudium
lectorum. Mirum est notare quam littera gothica, quam nunc
putamus parum claram, anteposuerit litterarum formas
humanitatis per seacula quarta decima et quinta decima. Eodem
modo typi, qui nunc nobis videntur parum clari, fiant sollemnes
in futurum."""

        # Add a tk.Text widget to Frame (self) and its configuration
        textwidget = tk.Text(self, wrap="none", font=("Comic Sans MS", 12),
                             padx=10, pady=10)
        textwidget.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nesw")
        # Add the text to textwidget and disable editing
        textwidget.insert(tk.END, text)
        textwidget.config(state=tk.DISABLED)

        # Here is where the HACK begins
        def is_scroll(wh, lower, upper):
            nonlocal size
            size[wh][0] = upper < '1.0' or lower > '0.0'
            size[wh][1] += 20 * size[wh][0] # += 1 for accuracy but slower
        # Call the is_scroll function when textwidget scrolls
        textwidget.config(xscrollcommand=lambda *args: is_scroll('w', *args),
                          yscrollcommand=lambda *args: is_scroll('h', *args))

        # Add a tk.Button to the Frame (self) and its configuration
        tk.Button(self, text="OK", command=self.quit).grid(row=1, column=0,
                                                           sticky="we")

        # For reasons of magic, hide root window NOW before updating
        root.withdraw()

        # Initially, make root window a minimum of 50 x 50 just for kicks
        root.geometry('50x50')
        size = {'w': [False, 50], 'h': [False, 50]}
        # Update to trigger the is_scroll function
        root.update()
        while size['w'][0] or size['h'][0]:
            # If here, we need to update the size of the root window
            root.geometry('{}x{}'.format(size['w'][1], size['h'][1]))
            root.update()

        # Center root window on mouse pointer
        x, y = root.winfo_pointerxy()
        root.geometry('+{}+{}'.format(x-size['w'][1]//2, y-size['h'][1]//2))

        # Now reveal the root window in all its glory
        root.deiconify()

        # Print textwidget dimensions to the console
        print(textwidget.winfo_width(), textwidget.winfo_height())

def main():
    """Show main window."""
    MyFrame().mainloop()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

**Explanation:**  The TRICK is to NOT even bother with the futility of trying to expand or shrink the Text widget directly.  The answer is a bit counter-intuitive, because one's FIRST thought is to go straight for that Text widget and do something to it.  Instead, expand the root (outermost) window (in this case, `self.master`), and just leave the Text widget alone.  Easy peasy.

Sticky (`"nesw"`) the Text widget to the Frame which is packed for 100% expansion in the root window.  As the root window expands, so will the Frame and the Text widget inside it.  However, as you're expanding the root window, TEST if the `lower` and `upper` bounds have vanished for the Text widget's `xscrollcommand`, and `yscrollcommand` (no more scrolling).  Those commands send `lower` and `upper` arguments as percentiles to a callback function needed for scrollbars, usually `tkinter.Scrollbar.set`.  However, we're using those commands because we do NOT WANT scrollbars or any scrolling at all.  We want a PERFECT FIT.

If the `lower` and `upper` bounds have vanished (lower <= 0.0 and upper >= 1.0), that means we have a perfectly fitted window around our Text widget which is also perfectly fitted around its text content.  TADA!

Added a button to demonstrate it still works correctly even with other widgets added.  Remove some text to see it still form-fits perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

**Edit**: short method:

```
text.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True, padx=0, pady=0)
```

---

By re-using sc0tt's answer, and Bryan Oakley's answer here [Get of number of lines of a Text tkinter widget](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20565149/get-of-number-of-lines-of-a-text-tkinter-widget), we can have this *ready-to-use* code (posted here for future reference) that also works for **proprtional fonts** :

```
import Tkinter as Tk
import tkFont

class Texte(Tk.Text):
    def __init__(self, event=None, x=None, y=None, size=None, txt=None, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.Text.__init__(self, master=root, *args, **kwargs)
        self.font = tkFont.Font(family="Helvetica Neue LT Com 55 Roman",size=35)
        self.place(x=10,y=10)
        self.insert(Tk.INSERT,' blah ')
        self.config(font=self.font)
        self.update_size(event=None)
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(2, "custom")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        self.bind_class("custom", "<Key>", self.update_size)

    def update_size(self, event):
        width=0
        lines=0
        for line in self.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n"):
            width=max(width,self.font.measure(line))
            lines += 1
        self.config(height=lines)
        self.place(width=width+10)

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("500x500")
Texte()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: You copied half of this code from my answer to another question. A citation or link to the other question would be nice. Regardless, you might want to mention in your answer that this only works for fixed width fonts. You can make it work with proportional fonts by actually measuring the width and height of each line.

Comment: Yes of course, I'll add a citation right now. By the way, I didn't post here for upvote or something like this (I already mentionned that I reused the accepted answer from sc0tt, so I claimed from the beginning that I didn't invent anything personnaly). I posted here only as reference if someone needs to reuse later.

Comment: Oh @BryanOakley, I didn't notice it works only for fixed width.... Such a shame. Do you have an idea on how to adapt it for proportionnal fonts

Comment: With `self.font.measure(line)` @BryanOakley,  I can measure the width in pixels, but this is not usable by `self.config(width=..., )`, right ?

Comment: you can get the font, the use the `font_measure` method to get the amount of pixels required to render a line of text. Or, you can use the `dlineinfo` method of the text widget. That only works for visible lines, but I assume that's not an issue in this specific case. Get the dimensions for every line, and do a little math.

Comment: in this code you're using place, and place allows you to set the width and height of a widget in pixels.

Comment: your questions are starting to get way off topic. If you need more information about measuring the height of a line, ask a separate question.

Comment: Updated the answer, it works for proportional fonts now.

Comment: I used `self.config(font=self.font)`  to reuse the same for Text's font and measurement's font, it works.

Comment: The update_size routine was definitely non-pythonesque, especially counting the lines.  Replace the loop with:  widths=map(lambda x:self.font.measure(x) for x in self.get("1.0", "end-1c").split("\n")) followed by width=max(widths) and lines=len(widths) then the rest of the code.

Answer (score 0):

Building on sc0tt's post, a helper function that works well if you are not using line breaks (e.g. just use a fixed width and make the height the only expanding variable):

```
def update_height(event):
    text_height = (str(event.widget.index('1.end')) )
    text_int = int(re.search(".(\d+)", text_height).group(1))
    widget_height = int(int(text_int)/160) + 1
    event.widget.config(height=widget_height)
```