# Get of number of lines of a Text tkinter widget

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I get the number of lines of a tkinter `Text` widget like this:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

def countlines(event):
    print float(event.widget.index(Tk.END))-1 
    print event.widget.get("1.0", Tk.END).count("\n")

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
a = Tk.Text(root)
a.pack()
a.bind("<Key>", countlines)

root.mainloop()
```

Only problem : when you hit `<Return>`, the count of lines doesn't increase. You need to add some futher text in order that count of lines increases.

**How to make that < Return > key increases the count of lines ?**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't get all the text and then count, just get the index of the last-minus-one character with `index("end-1c")` and then do some string manipulation to get the line number.

As for why the number doesn't increase, it's because your binding happens *before* the return key is inserted. For your simple test you can work around this by binding on `<KeyRelease>`, since the character is inserted on the press.

```
import Tkinter as Tk

def countlines(event):
    (line, c) = map(int, event.widget.index("end-1c").split("."))
    print line, c

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
a = Tk.Text(root)
a.pack()
a.bind("<KeyRelease>", countlines)

root.mainloop()
```

If you need to print the value on the key press, you'll have to use an advanced feature called "bindtags". Bindtags are covered briefly in an answer to this question: [Basic query regarding bindtags in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11541262/basic-query-regarding-bindtags-in-tkinter/11542200#11542200). In short, you have to create a custom bindtag that appears after the class bindtag, so that your binding happens after the class binding.

Here's how to modify your program to use bindtags:

```
import Tkinter as Tk

def countlines(event):
    (line, c) = map(int, event.widget.index("end-1c").split("."))
    print line, c

root = Tk.Tk()
root.geometry("200x200")
a = Tk.Text(root)
a.pack()
bindtags = list(a.bindtags())
bindtags.insert(2, "custom")
a.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
a.bind_class("custom", "<Key>", countlines)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks! Isn't it possible to get the count when the Key is **pressed** (and not *released*, because sometimes you hold the key for a long time) ?

Comment: @Basj: If you hold the key long enough it will start repeating and adding more than one character -- so it seems obvious you would want to wait until it was released.

Comment: No @martineau because I need to update display in realtime (it depends on realtime count of lines)

Comment: Thanks @BryanOakley ! It works ! (but I don't understand the index("end-1c")  ;) what is this "end-1c" ? and why split with "." ? why this char ?)

Comment: The text widget always adds an extra newline at the end, which you don't want to count. That's why "end-1c". We split on "." because `.index()` returns a string of the form "line.column" (eg: `1.0`, `2.14`, etc)