# How to get multiple tk.text widgets to adjust to content height?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm working on a gui with tcl/tk 8.5.9 and python 3.5.1 on Mac OS X 10.11.5.

I'm trying to create a sort of list of tk.text widgets that have a fixed width and adjust height to fit their content whenever it is changed (by the user or programmatically). This should take into account real as well as wrapped displaylines.

I got this to work using answers from [Tkinter Resize text to contents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11544187/tkinter-resize-text-to-contents) and [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/tkinter-discuss/2015-August/003751.html). However, adjusting to user input only works for the text widget that was created last. All previously created text widgets do not resize anymore, once a new one is added.

I think the problem might be somewhere in the lines that deal with the bindtags. Being new to tkinter, python and relatively new to programming in general, i'm not sure i understand bindtags properly.

Any help is much appreciated, here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class ResizingText(Text):

def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
    Text.__init__(self, master=parent, wrap='word', *args, **kwargs)

    # event binding on resize because text.count method for displaylines returns a wrong number when widget is instantiated
    self.bind('<Configure>', self.update_size)

    bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
    bindtags.insert(2, "custom")
    self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
    self.bind_class("custom", "<Key>", self.update_size)

def update_size(self, event):

    if self.winfo_width() > 1:
        self.unbind('<Configure>')

    displaylines = self.count("1.0", "end", "displaylines")
    self.config(height=displaylines)

root = Tk()

dynamic_text_1 = ResizingText(root, width=60)
dynamic_text_1.insert('1.0', "Longer text that is long enough to be wrapped into multiple display lines")
dynamic_text_1.grid(column=0, row=0)
# this text widget does not behave as expected:
# no resizing after user inputs a line break or a line long enough to be wrapped

dynamic_text_2 = ResizingText(root, width=60)
dynamic_text_2.insert('1.0', "Longer text that is long enough to be wrapped into multiple display lines")
dynamic_text_2.grid(column=0, row=1)
# this text widget behaves as expected

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I run your program and I can not reproduce your problem because whatever the length of the text I insert is, the heights are re-sized automatically to fit and wrap the text.

Comment: @BillalBEGUERADJ: thanks for your feedback, the problem concerns only resizing when the user inputs a line break or a line that gets wrapped. And the text widget last created behaves as i want. Also: i'm on Mac. I updated the question to clarify these points.

Answer (score 1):

I solved this by configuring the bindtags and resetting the event binding on Key-events every time the text widget gets the focus (event binding on FocusIn).

Probably not a clean solution, but it seems to work fine:

```
from tkinter import *

class ResizingText(Text):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        Text.__init__(self, master=parent, wrap='word', *args, **kwargs)

        # event binding on resize because text.count method for displaylines returns a wrong number when widget is instantiated
        self.bind('<Configure>', self.update_size)
        self.configure_bindtags(event=None)

        # solution: additional binding that resets the binding for <Key> events whenever the text widget gets the focus
        self.bind('<FocusIn>', self.configure_bindtags)

    def configure_bindtags(self, event):
        bindtags = list(self.bindtags())
        bindtags.insert(2, "custom")
        self.bindtags(tuple(bindtags))
        self.bind_class("custom", "<Key>", self.update_size)

    def update_size(self, event):
        if self.winfo_width() > 1:
            self.unbind('<Configure>')

        displaylines = self.count("1.0", "end", "displaylines")
        self.config(height=displaylines)

root = Tk()

dynamic_text_1 = ResizingText(root, width=60)
dynamic_text_1.insert('1.0', "Longer text that is long enough to be wrapped into multiple display lines")
dynamic_text_1.grid(column=0, row=0)

dynamic_text_2 = ResizingText(root, width=60)
dynamic_text_2.insert('1.0', "Longer text that is long enough to be wrapped into multiple display lines")
dynamic_text_2.grid(column=0, row=1)

root.mainloop()
```